# Webpage not displaing things as they should appear in opencart

Tags: html, css, ssl, compression, opencart

I am very new to stack over flow so please pardon my mistakes.

I am using opencart platform for my custom built ecommerce store. The website was woring perfectly till now, but I have just bought SSL certificate form comodo and installed it successfully to the store.

Now, I am facing an ISSUE of webpage streching or uncompressing, honestly I dont have an specific name for the problem but some of the experienced people can tell about it.

So, please suggest me something on the issue showed in the attached picture.

with https: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iauibyyymrpiz8/with%20https.png?dl=0

without https:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/60r1dvtoh2u60ec/without%20https.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I visited your website and its looks fine to me. There could be multiple possibilities for these kind of issues

1. Major one is Chrome, the browser itself. Many users face such issues you could possibly check and update your browser and Display Drivers if you haven't done that also try and check your website on other browsers too.
2. If you are using a 3rd Party template for your opencart installation, make sure your using the most up-to-date version of that theme and also make sure it matched with your current opencart version.
3. If you are using third party services such as cloudflare for DNS resolution and minification of Javascript, CSS and HTML make sure you turn off rocketloader and keep settings to default.

Hope that helps. Please keep me posted on this.

Also you mentioned you are using Comodo SSL certificate. Request you to read this page and make sure your website is secure.(https://blogs.comodo.com/e-commerce/heartbleed-bug-comodo-urges-openssl-users-to-apply-patch/)

In case the above points doesn't help make.I would request you to re-inspect your SSL installation (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/setting-up-payment-gateways/how-to-enable-ssl-connection-in-opencart)